# Call to a member function links() on a non-object

Tags: php, function, laravel, hyperlink, routes

The following code will throw an error

```
Call to a member function links() on a non-object
```

This is my route.php

```
Route::resource('dashboard/beasiswas', 'BeasiswasController');
```

BeasiswasController.php

```
class BeasiswasController extends BaseController {
    protected $beasiswas;

    public function __construct(Beasiswa $beasiswas){
        $this->$beasiswas = $beasiswas;
    } 

    public function index()
    {
        $beasiswas = DB::select("   select beasiswas.id, beasiswas.judul, beasiswas.created_at,  users.username as username
                                    from beasiswas
                                    LEFT JOIN 
                                    users 
                                    ON beasiswas.id_user = users.id
                                    LIMIT 3");              
        return View::make('beasiswas.index')->with('beasiswas',$beasiswas);
    }
}
```

index.blade.php

```
@foreach($beasiswas as $key => $beasiswa)
    {{ $no++ }}
    {{ $beasiswa->judul }}
    {{ $beasiswa->username }}
    {{ $beasiswa->created_at }}
@endforeach

{{ $beasiswas->links() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$beasiswas` is a collection. And you try to run `links()` method on this collection what obviously won't work. Probably you want to use `links()` method/relationship from some Eloquent model but when you don't use Eloquent you cannot use its method on data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want using links(), you need use `->paginate(int $x)`;

You are set static LIMIT. Use ->paginate and let Eloquent ORM set LIMIT